# Turning array elements as a function

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.
Let us assume that I have an array 
`var getfunction=["function1",fumction2","function3"... "functionN"]` and my aim is to turn this array elements as a functions  like function1();function2();.... functionN();

Is it possible ?

I tried like this:

```
   for (var k = 0; k < getfunction.length; k++) {
        debugger;
        var getvalue = getfunction[k];
        window[getfunction[k]] = function () { alert("hello world"); }
    }
```

but it is not working for me
it is showing error :
`Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function`

Comment: Referring to variables by names is a terrible idea at first place. That's what the arrays and objects are for. Create a JS object with functions assigned to properties, then you could resolve them as `obj_with_functions[function_name]`

Comment: Yeah, this works. I don't know why it's not working for you. This works for me.  `var names = ['f_one','f_two','f_three']; for( var n=0; n<names.length; n++ ){window[names[n]] = function(){console.log('Hi!')}} f_one();`  I do agree though that I advise against the theory behind this.

Comment: I don't understand: Do the functions *already* exist and you're trying to replace the strings related to them with references to them, or do you want to *create* functions with those names? In either case, really, why would your starting point be an array of function names?

Answer (score 0):

I need more explain to understand what's your problem, but as I supposed you may want to do this:

```
var arr = [ 'fn1', 'fn2' ];

for ( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++ )
    window[ arr[ i ] ] = function() { alert( 'Test functions' ); }

fn1();
fn2();
```

And the code above works completely fine and alerts twice 'Test functions'. Is there anything else to solve?